# How to change Navigation Drawer Icon

Tags: android, android-layout

Good Afternoon
I just have a quick question.
How do I change this icon in the navigation drawer.
I have been looking in google, but was confused with the answers..

[image: Navitagion Drawer default icon]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is an imageView in your `header_layout` or whatever you name it or Android Studio did.

Comment: Have you a drawer_header.xml or something similar into your layout directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your **layout** folder you need to look for **nav_header_main.xml**

Click on the very bottom where it says **Text** to see the XML lines and you should see an ImageView like this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
```

Change the **app:scrCompat** value for your drawable and thats it

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you a lot, I didn't noticed there was this xml under the layout, I already have a ton of stuff there, I was expecting to find it on the menu or drawbles.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

First import your icons into android studio then locate the nav_header.xml in the res/layout folder. change the src attribute in the image view

Comment: Thanks you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There will a layout included(nav_header.xml or similar named layout) in your XML. The name doesn't matter. Search for that and you can change a position there.

Comment: Thank you, didn't really noticed there was navbar stuff in the layout folder.